# iOS Image Resizing / Dealing With Blank Space

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, scaling

I have simply dragged UIImageView into storyboard and made it square.  I added a pink background to show the effects of the leftover space in the ImageView.  In each case I added either a taller image (1st image) and a wider image (2nd image), as well as a text label.  Here are my results.

[image: 1st image]

[image: 2nd image]

So the obvious question is....how can I get rid of this extra (pink) space and keep the integrity of the photo (that is, to not have to stretch or lose part of the image)?  If I wanted to be able to scroll through photos, it would be nice to have them all the same width to the edge so they look neat and orderly (if they were portrait), and if I wanted to have text under each, I'd want the text to be closer to it, rather than have all the blank (pink) space in between if it were landscape.  And obviously different size images will give different sizes of blank space.

So I'm thinking what I could do is before displaying the image, get the size of it, then just have a designated distance from either the label or the edge of screen, depending on the orientation of the picture, and then creating/changing the size of the UIImageView with a bit of math and using the image dimensions before inserting the picture into the ImageView.  Is this possible?  Is there another method I can't quite figure out?

Just look at any decent photo app and they are nice and neatly organized/displayed despite being different sizes, orientations, etc and I'm wondering how to pull this off.  I obviously haven't gotten too deep into using images past simply showing them in a pre-determined ImageView.

Thanks for the help/suggestions!

Comment: I can't visualize what it it is you want. Can you draw how those two images and their text _should_ be displayed, in your opinion?

Comment: Raptor,  They are being displayed exactly as how I would expect.  In the image of the landscape, it isn't as high as the number of pixels I made the UIImage view is, so when I did the Aspect Fit to keep the picture unskewed, there was extra (pink).  what I am asking is that because I only have used the drag and drop UIImageView, that causes a static size for it, so if the picture isn't that size, it has that extra padding leftover if the picture isn't the exact dimensions, and I want to eliminate that.

Comment: So basically get rid of the pink so I have room for more pictures nicely above and below....if I don't do that, then different size pictures will have different "leftover" pink and then as you scroll down through them, they won't be vertically spaced correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this... set your UIImageView to AspectFit (not AspectFill since that will lose some of the image) and using constraints do the following:

- centre the UIImageView in the container both horizontally and vertically
- set the UILabel to float below the UIImageView by whatever distance you desire ("standard" is usually good)
- set the left, right, and top constraints on the UIImageView to be >= whatever distance you desire
- set the bottom constraint on the UILabel to be (once again) >= whatever distance you desire

The effect of this *should* be that the UIImageView will properly resize itself to its intrinsic size and the constraints should properly position it and the label.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I have used the Aspect Fit and that's about it.  My intuition is that it will do these constraints and then put the image it and things might be skewed and not what I want.  I only say that because my previous work with autolayout was very gruesome for a while before I got what I wanted.  But I will definitely give this a shot.  Thanks.  If not, I'll attempt to hardcode some things which might actually be easier for me to understand since autolayout for me is no bueno.